# Does using one Random object across multiple classes make it less random for each?

Tags: c#, random

If I have two classes that each take a pseudo random number generator (PRNG) as a dependency and I pass the same PRNG instance to both, does that compromise the PRNG algorithm? For example, in the code below, each class ends up using every other random number of the same sequence in the while loop since they share the same generator. Is it more proper for each class to get a separate instance or does it matter?

```
Random rand = new Random();
RandomBool randBool = new RandomBool(rand);
RandomFirstName randFirstName = new RandomBool(rand);

while(<condition>)
{
    bool myBool = randBool.Next();
    string myName = randFirstName.Next();
    Console.WriteLine(myName + " " + myBool.ToString());
}
```

Comment: it shouldn't really matter, as far as you are not into something very critical crypto-wise. otherwise you'll need a real RNG instead of a PRNG, but if PRNG is enough for your need, then using the same random object should be enough.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you have **only one thread**, it is best to use the same `Random` instance all over.

(If it is a multithreaded application, either lock or have one instance per thread; `Random` will not work with multithreading.)

Answer (score 3):

NO, actually the other way around.

As per MSDN: [Random Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx)

"[...] This problem [of same generated sequence] can be avoided by creating a single Random object rather than multiple ones. To improve performance, create one Random object to generate many random numbers over time, instead of repeatedly creating a new Random objects to generate one random number."

Also the page says that any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to do something fancy like correlation induction strategies for variance reduction, that requires synchronizing your randomness across replications and is much easier if you use separate instances of the PRNG.  But if you're just doing straight-up sampling, it's fine to use the same PRNG for multiple purposes.

Comment: Thanks, pjs. I think my next SO question is going to be "what is a correlation induction strategy for variance reduction?"... :)

Comment: @MikeBundy See [variance reduction/common random numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance_reduction) and [antithetic variates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetic_variates).